# How to make image link inline next to button?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I've had this issue where I've tried to make an image link appear next to a button, but the image link jumps to the next line. What I'm trying to do is make a 'SIZE GUIDE' image link appear next to an 'ADD TO BAG' button. Text links don't jump to the next line, I've experimented with a 'hey' text link.

The 'hey' link is where I want the 'SIZE GUIDE' button to show up. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display:block` from this rule:

```
a img {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
}
```

or create a class that uses `display:inline` and assign it to that image.

Comment: Okay that worked but how can I just make it for just that image link?

Comment: give that img link an `id` in the HTML and call that when you put this CSS in.  you wont need the `a img` part if you use the `#id-name`.

Comment: I just gave it a class. Thanks! You were a huge help!